# Is Rinkeby still working?

Tags: rinkeby

I followed the process by creating a tweet with my wallet Ethereum ID and submitted it but I didnt get Ethereum in my wallet.

Does the wallet have to be from a particular exchange?

My wallet address is 0xe7D0A858d258a1B664e86bee07B8E6D22432b627

Comment: Rinkeby is working. The address that you provided has 21.75 ETH. 

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xe7D0A858d258a1B664e86bee07B8E6D22432b627

Comment: Thanks but I cannot find the ethereum in my blockchain wallet.

Comment: The link that I show above shows the balance in you account, what do you mean when you say that you can not find the ether in your blockchain wallet?

Comment: I copied the address from my blockchain wallet for receiving ethereum. Is the Rinkeby Ethereum different form the Ethereum in my wallet?

Comment: Also, can you recommend a wallet for holding Rinkeby Ethereum?

Comment: the same wallet that you use for mainnet will work for rinkeby, you should change networks manually. The easiest way is to use metamaks, with a single click you will switch between mainnet and any other available testnet like rinkeby

Comment: Thanks, I just found my Rinkeby Ether on MetaMask. However, I found only 18.75 ether in the wallet. I appreciate your help.